# Why does using a function object argument in std::transform fail and require a lambda expression instead

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, functor

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses) question I got a good understanding of functors (function objects); how to initialize and call them. I wrote some code to play around with this for my own understanding

```
class Foo
{
private:
   int x;
public:
   Foo(int x) : x(x) {}
   int operator()(int y) { return x + y; }
};

Foo poo(50);

int a = poo(50);

std::cout << a;

std::vector<int> vec(10);
std::vector<int> pec(10);

std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), poo(1));
```

and receive the following compilation error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2064   term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

I looked within the above question at some of the comments and tried a lambda  expression instead

`std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), [](Foo poo) {return poo(1); });`

which works but I don't understand why the accepted answer using `std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), out.begin(), add_x(1));` fails.  Why do I have to use a lambda expression?  Another answer is doing the same thing but it still will result in a compilation error.  Why is that?

Comment: It sounds like a typo. `poo(1)` -> `Foo(1)`.

Comment: I think it's more of a case of the somewhat misleading error message making you miss the fact that you're referencing something that doesn't exist: `poo`.

Comment: `poo(1)` is an `int`; as the error message says, it it not a function taking 1 argument. `Foo(1)` is a function object with an `operator()` that takes a single argument of type `int`.

Comment: I misunderstood the results from the question.  I thought I could pass the function object into the transform rather than the class object.

Comment: What is the reason for  overloading () anyway?

Comment: @SaeidYazdani I'm practicing function objects in c++11 and may be doing something I don't need to because I'm a noob trying to learn this complex language but I have good references to learn from.

Answer (score 3):

This code works just fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

class add_x
{
private:
   int x;

public:
   add_x(int x) : x(x) {}

   int operator()(int y) /* consider adding const here */
   { return x + y; }
};


int main()
{
    std::array<int, 5> input { 1, 4, 9, 16, 25 };
    std::array<int, 5> output;
    std::transform(begin(input), end(input), begin(output), add_x(1));
    for ( auto& val : output ) std::cout << val << "\n";
}
```

However, it's probably a good idea to make the invocation a `const` member function since it doesn't mutate the functor.  That may also make it work with more versions of the Standard library.

The difference between this and your lambda version is that here, the constant `1` is passed to the constructor to create one functor object, and the data are passed sequentially to the operator of that single functor instance.  In your lambda, a new object is created from each datum by calling the conversion constructor, and then the constant is passed to the operator.  That is, `x` and `y` are swapped by your workaround, and also the number of instances changed.

Answer (score 1):

It also works if you add a definition:

```
Foo poo(1);
```

and just send poo into transform, without the (1) invocation. Transform requires an object with a () operator to call, and declaring it separately makes it a little more clear what its scope is.

Comment: yeah define `Foo poo(1)` and then pass into the transformer `poo`.  Good idea.